# How to add multiple users to a single auth_group in Django

Tags: python, django, python-3.6, django-1.8

I have a list of users and an auth group called 'group1'. These users are created through the `bulk_create` method in Django. Now I need to add all these users to group 'group1'.
I can achieve this with a for loop like:

```
group1 = Groups.objects.get(name='group1') 
for user in users:
    group1.user_set.add(user)
```

but I am wondering if there are any easy and better ways without using the for loop.

Comment: Note that Django 1.8 is end-of-life and does not receive support updates, and that it does not officially support Python 3.6.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `add()` method accepts a list of objects:

```
group1 = Groups.objects.get(name='group1') 
group1.user_set.add(*users)
```

This is slightly tidier, but I'm not sure you'll notice any difference in performance.

See the docs on [many-to-many relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/#many-to-many-relationships) for more info.